# SSRS Web Application Error. Having version issues

Tags: reporting-services

Here is what I have and I'm sure it is versioning but I can't seem to figure it out.
Visual Studio 2019
Framework : 4.7.2

This was Framework 3.5 and I upgraded to version 4.7.2. It was working until I open a report to edit and then it wants to edit the Report (RDLC).

Error1: Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll'      D:\Development\Work\asedra\Website\Reports\RptViolation.aspx    44

Error 2 : ASP.NET session has expired

Web.config:

```
 <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
 </buildProviders>

 <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </assemblies>
```

rdlc

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

the web page (.aspx)

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error1**: Register `ReportViewer` on .aspx like this

`<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>`

Add to web.config this line

`<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>`

**Error2**: Store session state on SQL server. Here's a guide: [HOW TO: Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317604/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-asp-net-session-state).

Basically, you need to create *ASPState* database, activate *ASP.NET State Service* and add this line to the web.config:

`<sessionState 
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
    />`